# How to manage table ownership in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database-schema, create-table, sql-grant

Team,

Could you guide me :

1. how to find out the table owner in mysql  ?
2. how to alter the table ownership to another user in mysql ?

Answer (score 10):

There is no such thing as a table owner in MySQL.

A table typically belongs to a schema (ie a database), but not to a user.

The way to enforce access control is to use [`GRANT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) or [`REVOKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/revoke.html) to give or withdraw privilieges or roles to users (or roles) :

```
GRANT  SELECT, INSERT ON mydb.mytbl TO   'someuser'@'somehost';
REVOKE SELECT, INSERT ON mydb.mytbl FROM 'someuser'@'somehost';
```